# Вывод записи из БД в ListView, поле которой совпало с текстом из текстбокса

Tags: c#, sql, select, like

Программа должна выводить из базы данных строку, значение которой в поле `Author` полностью или частично совпал со значением, введенным в текстбокс `SearchTBR`. Выдает ошибку: не может прочитать *sql запрос* (9 строка).

```
if (Convert.ToString(SearchTBR.Text) != "")
            {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source = .\\mysql; initial catalog = Library; integrated security = true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "select BookID, Author, Title, YEAR(Year), Category, Availability from Bibliography where (Author 
LIKE  '% & SearchTBR.Text & %')";
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[3].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[5].ToString());
                    listViewLLReader.Items.Add(lv);
                }
                cn.Close(); 
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут

```
cmd.CommandText = "select BookID, Author, Title, YEAR(Year), Category, Availability from Bibliography where (Author LIKE  '% & SearchTBR.Text & %')";
```

я так понимаю, имели ввиду

```
cmd.CommandText = "select BookID, Author, Title, YEAR(Year), Category, Availability from Bibliography where (Author LIKE  '%"+SearchTBR.Text+"%')";
```